# TypeError: Cannot read property - React, Api, Json

Tags: массивы, json, reactjs, api

В массиве, при обращении к первому уровню, данные получаю без проблем.

При обращении ко второму уровню

Получаю ошибку **TypeError: Cannot read property 'yandex' of undefined**

**Массив**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ошибка**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо в момент первого рендера ваш запрос еще не вернул результат.

Comment: Но первый уровень например {this.state.reports.code} - вернет 200, что верно.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых не используйте [componentWillMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount), так как этот хук не поддерживатся в новых версиях React.

Во вторых добавьте проверку в свой код:

```
<td>Запросы ({this.state.reports.positions && this.state.reports.positions.yandex && this.state.reports.positions.yandex.count})
```

Скорее всего у Вас в изначальном стейте уже есть `reports`:

```
this.state = {
  reports: []
}
```

и из-за этого в `this.state.reports.code` не возникает ошибки, потому что там просто `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема была в неправильно указанном свойстве.

```
this.state = {
            user: [],
            reports: []
        }
```

Изменил на

```
this.state = {
                user: null,
                reports: null
            }
```